# The action defined in .htaccess doesn't execute

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wampserver

I installed [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/) on my Windows 7 laptop.

Next, I defined an alias (WAMPSERVER -> Apache -> Alias directories -> Add an alias)

```
Alias name: test
Alias directory: c:/test
```

Next, I've placed a PHP file into that directory (`c:/test/foo.php`). I executed the URL `http://localhost/test/foo.php` in my browser and the PHP file was successfully retrieved.

Now, I added an `.htaccess` file into that same directory (`c:/test/.htaccess`) with the following content:

```
Action     controller-test /foo.php
AddHandler controller-test .tst
```

Finally, I tried to execute the URL `http://localhost/test/testing.tst` in my browser but I got a "404 Not found" page. Shouldn't the `foo.php` page have been retrieved? What am I doing wrong?

(I followed the instructions from [this article](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html).)

---

I have also added the line `IndexIgnore */*` to the `.htaccess` file which caused the directory listing to be hidden, so I can confirm that the `.htaccess` file works.

Answer (score 2):

From the article you followed: "*The executable named by Action is relative to the document root.*"

So you have to move `foo.php` one level up or write

```
Action     controller-test /test/foo.php
```

Comment: This - `Action controller-test /test/foo.php` - doesn't seem to make a difference. I can't go up one level, because I'm already at the root of my alias. I would like to be within the bounds of my alias if possible...